# Нужен ли flash в моем случае?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

Хочу создать блок с двумя картинками 1 поверх другого. При клика на изображения выделенная область мишки верхнего слоя должно стать прозрачным и показывать нижний слой картинки.
При этом курсор мишки становиться фигуркой, кокой нибудь губки.
То есть нужно создать имитацию ластика что-ли, чтоб верхний слой очистить и показывать нижний.
Так вот можно ли обойтись без flash на html5, html, javascript? или в каком направлении мне искать?
Если есть примеры дайте ссылку. А если все решается куском когда и если можете покажите как?
Надеюсь ясно выразился, Спасибо.

Comment: Конечно можно и на html5, но если есть опыт на флеш - можно и на флеш (пока он не умер).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian опыта на флеш нету но в html5 разбираюсь но вот не могу понять как это можно на html5 реализовать. Можете указать путь от чего начать или пару слов как можно реализовать что, какие элементы использовать?

Comment: Ну тогда как обычно - рисуете на канве, там же стираете, вот можете здесь подсмотреть демка и исходниками (включая ластик для стирания) http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/#demo-complete

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Ваш пример оказался очень интересным но, я просмотрел и ластик там просто рисует белым цветом. А нет каких нибудь примеров в котором ластик делает выделенную часть изображения прозрачным?

Comment: Может вы другой пример смотрите, там несколько. Вот https://gyazo.com/dd240154960f3c368881bcb77d99c4d7 на уточке сначала фиолетовым рисую, затем ластиком линию провожу - получается белая линия, но с уткой, т.е. это стирается фиолтеовая закраска, а утка остается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просмотрев похожие вещи создал и улучшал решения этой проблемы. Решения в другом вопросе по ссылке [Нужно улучшать очистку на canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546501/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

Пройдитесь по этим ссылкам:)

codepen.io/progrape/pen/XXBwWe - Ваш случай

jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/WUXDb/1/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907163/html5-canvas-eraser-tool-without-overdraw-white-color